# CSS menu not working on tablets

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML, which is for my menu:

```
<div id="cssmenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Homepage</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Projects</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Services</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><span>LINK</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The sub menu links are not working on an iPad - the sub menu does not show it just goes to the link.

Here is a fiddle for the whole menu: *http://jsfiddle.net/q3eXH/*

Comment: I'm not seeing any submenus show up in the jsfiddle either. Are you by chance missing some javascript?

Comment: hover over Services - works for me on the fiddle

Comment: Do you mean on hover the sub menus are not showing (in tablets)?

Comment: Oh I see, my browser window was too small.

Comment: Seems to work fine on my iPhone.

Comment: Hovers don't really make sense on a tablet/ipad. You could do some device detection and come up with another option for those users. Some ideas here: http://www.prowebdesign.ro/how-to-deal-with-hover-on-touch-screen-devices/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a checkbox to toggle the drop-down using CSS no Javascript is required

http://jsfiddle.net/Victornpb/q3eXH/3/

CSS

```
#cssmenu input[type="checkbox"]:checked + ul,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}

#cssmenu input[type="checkbox"]{
    display:none;
}
```

HTML

```
<li>
    <label for="c1">
        <span>Services</span>
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c1">

    <!-- sub-menu -->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span>LINK</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This script will make touch devices show active states on tap:

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){}, true);
```

Another tip to improve your users´ experience is to include [this](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) plugin.